# restore a backup from duplicity

Tags: backup, duplicity

I lost everything on my computer but hopefully I made several backups with duplicity. My problem is that I can't restore these backups. I tried a couple of commands like

```
duplicity restore file:///media/backup_path /home/user/destination_file
```

but I get these errors

```
Import of duplicity.backends.dpbxbackend Failed: No module named dropbox
Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
Copying duplicity-new-signatures.20140728T081856Z.to.20140729T071746Z.sigtar.gz to local cache.
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/media/134b04a8-bba0-4477-ab48-fd443c9ad3d4/duplicity-new-signatures.20140728T081856Z.to.20140729T071746Z.sigtar.gz'
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I restore a backup on a different computer than it was made?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516774/can-i-restore-a-backup-on-a-different-computer-than-it-was-made)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. These instructions are for a fresh ubuntu install.

1. Open Déjà Dup. Search the dash for deja.
2. Click on the big “Restore” button.

   [image]
3. A dialog will appear asking where your backup files are stored (your “Backup location”). Choose “Other…” and navigate to the folder of backups. On this same screen, select whether you encrypted the backup or not. Click “Forward”.

   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Choose the date you want to restore from. Usually you can just leave this alone, as the default is the most recent backup. Click “Forward”.
5. Choose where to restore. Since this is a full system backup, leave it as the default (to restore over your current install). Click “Forward”.
6. Review your selections and click “Restore”.
7. Wait. Your files won’t appear in your home directory until the entire restore is finished. It may take a while.
8. Reinstall any programs that you enjoyed in your previous install.

Taken from [the deja dup help wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/Full).