# How to restore a Déjà Dup Backup file at command prompt with duplicity

Tags: command-line, backup, deja-dup, restore, duplicity

I have used Déjà Dup Backup Tool to backup to external hard disk (`/media/TOSHIBA EXT/`)

Now I want to test the backup. So I deleted one test file (`/home/rch/hecatombe.txt`).

I can restore that file via Nautilus "File => Restore Missing Files" (as at [restore a backup from duplicity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504498/restore-a-backup-from-duplicity) )

But I prefer to work at the command prompt.

So I deleted that test file again, and did this at the command prompt:

```
duplicity restore --no-encryption "file:///media/TOSHIBA EXT/" "/home/rch/hecatombe.txt"
```

But instead of restoring my file `hecatombe.txt`, `duplicity` made a new directory `hecatombe.txt` with contents like this `/home/rch/locate_hecatombe.txt/home/rch`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As you may have guessed, `duplicity` asks for a directory as the second argument when restoring files. According to [`man duplicity`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/duplicity.1.html):

> ```
> duplicity [restore] [options] [--file-to-restore <relpath>] [--time time] source_url target_directory
> ```
>
> ...
>      If we wanted to restore just the file "Mail/article" in
>       `/home/me` as it was three days ago into `/home/me/restored_file`:
>
> ```
> duplicity -t 3D --file-to-restore Mail/article
> sftp://uid@other.host/some_dir /home/me/restored_file
> ```

So, in your case, you would use:

```
duplicity restore --no-encryption --file-to-restore hecatombe.txt "file:///media/TOSHIBA EXT/" "/home/rch/"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed reply. 

But when I try:- 

$ duplicity restore --no-encryption --file-to-restore hecatombe.txt "file:///media/TOSHIBA EXT/" "/home/rch/"

I get:- 
    Import of duplicity.backends.sshbackend Failed: No module named paramiko /
    Restore destination directory /home/rch/ already exists. /
    Will not overwrite.  

( Perhaps the missing "module named paramiko" is the problem? )

Comment: @user2893515 I think duplicity expects to create the directory it will restore the files to (to prevent overwriting existing files, I suppose). Does using a directory like `/home/rch/does_not_exist` work?

Comment: re:- **Does using a directory like /home/rch/does_not_exist work?**
Thank you! Your suggestion cures the error message:- 
_Restore destination directory /home/rch/ already exists. Will not overwrite._

And I cured the error message  _No module named paramiko_ with
**sudo apt-get install  python-paramiko** 

But I still have problems. Nautilus _Restore Missing File_ finds the deliberately deleted file
"/home/rch/locate_geany.txt" but 
**duplicity restore  --file-to-restore "/home/rch/locate_geany.txt" ... "**
returns
 _/home/rch/locate_geany.txt not found in archive, no files restored._

Comment: @user2893515 duplicity events a relative path. So if the backup was made from `/home/rch` you will have to have leave out that part.

Comment: Still no joy. _duplicity restore --no-encryption --file-to-restore "locate_geany.txt" "file:///media/TOSHIBA EXT/" "/home/rch/foobar"_
 says
**locate_geany.txt not found in archive, no files restored.**
Same for _--file-to-restore "/home/rch/locate_geany.txt"_
(and no warning is given even when _/home/rch/locate_geany.txt_ exists).
Yet **Nautilus Restore Missing File** finds _locate_geany.txt_ and says **Your file was successfully restored**
    and puts it back in its original directory

Comment: @user2893515 what was your original backup command, and where did `locate_geany.txt` originally exist?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:-

Forget duplicity.
*Use deja-dup's command line option.*

Thus:-  **deja-dup --restore /path/filename**

e.g. "deja-dup --restore  /home/rch/locate_geany.txt"

With thanks to [Fedora :-)](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9483/how-to-restore-a-file-from-a-deja-dup-backup-quickly/)

Answer (score 0):

```
duplicity restore --force  sourceUrl targetpath
```

should do the trick but will override existing files
unlike with

```
deja-dup --restore-missing
```

option