Restore a single file with deja-dup in Ubuntu 20.04
I tried to restore a single file in Nautilus that I have accidentally overwritten. However, the context-menu entry to restore a (missing) file is no longer there. After some research I found, that the deja-dup Nautilus extension is no longer available but that a file-browser is integrated in deja-dup from version 42.0. However, since I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I am not able to upgrade deja-dup beyond version 40.7. So there so the context menu in Nautilus has gone but also there is no file-browser in deja-dup as well. Is there a way around that? It's not very practical having to restore all files when I actually just need one.
Thanks for your help.

Is Deja Dup not the version from the Ubuntu software center? If you stick with the version that comes with the distribution, all functionality is preserved. If you do not manage to get it working through the GUI, a last resort remains to use duplicity at the command line to restore the file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/504669/how-to-restore-a-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-dup-backup-file-at-command-prompt-with-duplicity


Open a terminal and cd to the folder where the file filename is (or was).
If a version exists, rename it mv filename filename-bad or whatever
Give the command deja-dup --restore filename

This will start a GUI which allows you to specify which backup to restore from. Work through the windows that appear and it will restore your file.
You could also get the missing file functionality by using deja-dup --restore-missing directoryname but as you know the filename the above steps are quicker.
