# Restore individual folders from full backup using duplicity/deja

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver). I would like to selectively restore some folders from a backup performed using duplicity on Ubuntu 12.04 to avoid overriding my home folder. The backup is stored on an external drive. Two questions would follow.

First question, is there a way to a extract a single folder instead of the full backup restore using the Deja/Dup GUI? The answer provided in [Is it possible to restore only one directory with the backup utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181272/is-it-possible-to-restore-only-one-directory-with-the-backup-utility)  is outdated and would not work for fresh installs.

Restoring the entire backup to a different folder and then copying individual folders, as stated in [Can I restore a backup on a different computer than it was made?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516774/can-i-restore-a-backup-on-a-different-computer-than-it-was-made), would not be convenient due to storage issues.

Second Question, is there another GUI programs alternative for duplicity other than Deja/Dup that can do that? Otherwise, the way to go is following the steps in the following link: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase#Restoring_by_Hand

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The old method of restoring via right-click in Nautilus *should* work. The only time that option is not available in the context menu is when you are in a folder that is not included in the current backup settings. On your fresh install, make sure you have configured the backup *exactly* like on the old install.

A little technical background: Nautilus doesn't check what backups currently exist on the system. In fact, doing so would take a long time and cannot be done everytime you right-click on a folder. It only checks which folders are *scheduled* for backup and shows the option whenever you are in such a folder.

(Also, it seems like it doesn't check for exclusion filters – even in excluded folders, the restore option is available if the parent folder is included. Deja-dup won't restore anything though if you actually click it.)

If you still don't succeed on your machine for whatever reason, you can use this method instead:

```
deja-dup --restore [File1 File2 ...]
```

will restore individual files if you know their names.

```
deja-dup --restore-missing [Directory]
```

will restore the files that have been deleted from the given directory.

Note that both of these commands will bring up the Deja-Dup Restore GUI, which will also allow you to specify the backup source. You don't need to do the whole task on the command line.